# What programs can I use to separate clusters of vector objects

Tags: vector, eps

I just purchased a group pack of background images from Shutterstock (.eps file). I don't have Adobe Illustrator. Is there a cheap program I can download to separate these individual backgrounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape can handle EPS

https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#How_to_open_EPS_files_in_Windows

> Initially you need to find out where ps2pdf is on your machine or
>   install it. It's in the Ghostscript lib directory, which is probably
>   something like C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\lib.
>
> If it is not installed you may find a current release of Ghostscript
>   for Windows on their download page here.
>
> Then you need to add this to the system Path in Environment Variables.
>   To navigate there on Win XP, Vista, 7: Start button > Control Panel >
>   System > Advanced > Environment Variables. In Windows 8.1/10,
>   right-click on This PC, choose Properties > Advanced system settings >
>   Advanced tab > Environment Variables. Scroll through the System
>   variables in the bottom panel, and select Path, click Edit. In the
>   ridiculously small edit box provided add a semicolon to the end of
>   whatever is there at the moment, and then add C:\Program
>   Files\gs\gs9.16\lib (or whatever it is on your machine).  Note --
>   There should be no space between the semicolon and C (the start of the
>   path).
>
> You will also need to add the Ghostscript bin directory after another
>   semicolon to the system Path. (This will be the same as the lib
>   directory, but ending in bin rather than lib - for example: C:\Program
>   Files\gs\gs9.16\bin)
>
> Note that updating to a new version of Ghostscript will install to a
>   new \gs directory, but will not erase the old version subdirectory or
>   update the Environment Variables.You'll need to delete the old
>   directories and Environmental Variable paths if you want to make use
>   of the newly installed version (with the new directory and paths). 
>   Also note that if you have a 64-bit system, and you install the 32-bit
>   version of Ghostscript, the paths will be C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/...etc., instead of C:/Program Files/...etc.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try Inkscape but I actually use a Mac not a PC.

Comment: @KLC - Inkscape is cross-platform (Mac/Windows/Linux).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible tools, I'm including illustrator so that the list is more  complete. A non-comprehensive list in alphabetic order:

- [Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/products/acrobat-pro.html), commercial.
- [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), commercial.
- [Corel Draw](http://www.coreldraw.com/rw/), commercial.
- [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/), open source.
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), open source.
- [Karbon](https://www.calligra.org/karbon/), open source.
- [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/), commercial, OSX only.
- [Xara Designer Pro](http://www.xara.com/us/designer-pro/), commercial. Older version available for free on linux

You can also edit the bounding box with any text editor in existence. Heres an [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171455/what-is-a-good-workflow-for-importing-and-cropping-eps-images)